# PHP constant string square bracket indexing

Tags: php, string, arrays, indexing, constants

I'm trying to get a constant string and index it as if it was an array of characters (square bracket syntax).  When I try this code it fails on the last line.

```
define( 'CONSTANT_STRING','0123456789abcdef');
echo CONSTANT_STRING; // Works by itself :)
$string = CONSTANT_STRING;
echo $string[9]; // Also works by itself.
echo strlen(CONSTANT_STRING); // Also works by itself.

echo substr(CONSTANT_STRING, 9, 1); // Ok, yes this works, but not as clean.

echo CONSTANT_STRING[9]; // Fails as a syntax (parse) error.
```

I am using a constant string like this in a function.  Since it could be called multiple times on one page it really should be a constant.  What is the best option if there is no way to do this like I originally intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PHP Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) can only be scalar values, so the engine doesn't try to properly parse a constant that's used as something more than a scalar, like an array or an object.

This is a problem in your case because the brackets are used to point at an array index *and* can be used as a shortcut to grab a character at a specific location in the string.

You'll just have to do it the "hard" way and use [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).